# How to get value from table1, search in table2, and after found - get a row value of the first value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have `table1`, here I have a data of `id`s from `table2` - that look like that: (I dont know how to create here a table)

```
id | word1 | word2

1  |   5   |   7
```

So I want to get the `word1` and `word2` values from `table1`, search them in `table2`, and after that get them `word_name` value in `table2`. here`s what I do:

```
SELECT a.word1, a.word2, b.word_name FROM table1 a, table2 b WHERE b.id = a.word1 OR b.id = a.word2
```

and nothing happend.

Comment: which is the common column in both table?

Comment: in `table1` its called `word1` and `word2` that in `table2` I have `id`

Comment: here you are matching column values with row values...so that multiple rows from table 2 matches with single row of table 1

Comment: @Ashu so how its need to be?

Comment: check 5,7 id available in table 2 in id column..

Comment: @Ashu its available, I have rows from 1-3000 `id`

Comment: its working at my side & display result with multiple rows

Comment: See how sathvik reddy answered? That's how to ask.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, here is the sample data:

### id, word1_id, word2_id

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS id (`id` INT,`w1` INT,`w2` INT
);
INSERT INTO id VALUES
(1,1,5),
(2,2,4),
(3,8,3),
(4,6,2),
(5,7,1),
(6,4,9),
(7,5,7),
(8,2,6),
(9,3,8);`
```

### Word table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS word (
    `w_id` INT,
    `word` VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8
);
INSERT INTO word VALUES
(1,'one'),
(2,'two'),
(3,'three'),
(4,'four'),
(5,'five'),
(6,'six '),
(7,'seven'),
(8,'eight'),
(9,'nine');`
```

### And here is the answer:

```
select id.w1,id.w2,w1.word,w2.word from id
join word w1 on w1.w_id = id.w1
join word w2 on w2.w_id = id.w2;

7   1   seven   one
6   2   six     two
8   3   eight   three
2   4   two     four
1   5   one     five
2   6   two     six 
5   7   five    seven
3   8   three   eight
4   9   four    nine
```

and let me know if that worked.!

Comment: Its possible to show the name by `WHERE`? for example to use `LIKE CONCAT` to show only the words start with the letter `S`?

Comment: Hi, please see my last comment.